How to make input shape same for time distributed layer when having CNN-LSTM model
I have extracted MFCC from audio files and stored them in json. Here are some detail about the input shape:
X_train shape: (1272, 130, 13, 1) X_validation shape: (318, 130, 13, 1) X_test shape: (530, 130, 13, 1) input_shape = (X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1)
I want to run CNN-LSTM together so I came up with this model:
def build_model(input_shape):


    # We will use a Sequential model for model construction.
    model = keras.Sequential()
    
    # Define the Model Architecture.
    ########################################################################################################################
    
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same',activation = 'relu'),
                              input_shape = input_shape))
    
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((4, 4), padding='same'))) 
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))
    
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',activation = 'relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((4, 4), padding='same')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))
    
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same',activation = 'relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))
    
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same',activation = 'relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))
                                      
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
                                      
    # model.add(LSTM(32))
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=input_shape, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64))

    # dense layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
                                      
    model.add(Dense(7, activation = 'softmax'))

    ########################################################################################################################

    # Display the models summary.
    model.summary()
    
    # Return the constructed LRCN model.
    return model

But it gave me error stating that  ->
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling LSTMCell.call().
Dimensions must be equal, but are 64 and 192 for '{{node sequential_10_1/lstm_10_1/lstm_cell_1/MatMul}} = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false](sequential_10_1/lstm_10_1/strided_slice_2, sequential_10_1/lstm_10_1/lstm_cell_1/Cast/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,64], [192,256].
I was expecting it to run smoothly because now the input shape of my CNN and time distributed layer are same.

Do you give the full shape of X_train (1272, 130, 13, 1) as input_shape to the network? For the input_shape parameter of a network, you omit the batch dimension.

Earlier I have given this: input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1) but it also gave the same error

Your input shape has one dimension too few for TimeDistributed and Conv2D. Assuming that the first dim of X_train is the batch dim, Conv2D needs 3 other dimensions (height, width, channels) and time distributed needs another dimension to unwrap it "over time".
